# Как в URL заменить GET на "/" с помощью htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Как в URL заменить GET на "/" с помощью htaccess для следующего примера?

Дан адрес:

> temp-name.local/about?page=certificates

Необходимо, чтобы получилось:

> temp-name.local/about/certificates

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту задачу или в какую сторону "копать"?

Comment: Это ж в каждом втором конфиге написано

Comment: Да, проблемка в том, что стили CSS не применяются. Как то частично работает. Без графики.

Comment: Пример привел в описании вопроса. Это работает, но без стилей почему то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В .htaccess прописываем:

```
RewriteRule ^about/([A-Za-z]+) about.php?page=$1
```

Внутри тега  помещаем:

```
<base href="/">
```

Это необходимо для отображения стилей и изображений